# Slide two item, and show and indicator at bottom, RecyclerView or ViewPager should use?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

**i need Slide two item, and show and indicator at bottom, RecyclerView or ViewPager should use?**

[image: Slide two image, with indeictor]

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewpager and override getPageWidth in the PagerAdapter implementation for having two items in each view like below :

```
@Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return (super.getPageWidth(position) / 2);
    }
```

and for showing indicator, you can use TabLayout and connect that with ViewPager programmatically like this:

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
PagerAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), items);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);

TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager, true);
```

and some custom tab_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_dot"
          android:state_selected="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_dot"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for the answer

Comment: I would be grateful if you make my answer an accepted answer for this question @HiPradeep